# The second someone realizes (or realized) if the preceding action is in the past tense?

Tags: grammar

For the given sentence

> She waited patiently for the rare moment when EVERYONE in the house was out, and went straight for the plastic bag the second she realized she is free

Should it be "she realizes she is free" or "she realized she is free", given the preceding action "went straight for the plastic bag" is already in the past tense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the mismatch here is "she realized she **is** free". Changing it to "she realized she **was** free" would make the tense of the sentence uniform. In this case, the sentence could be rewritten either way, depending on the larger context:

**Present Tense**

> She **waits** patiently for the rare moment when EVERYONE in the house **is** out, and **goes** straight for the plastic bag the second she **realizes** she is free

**Past Tense**

> She waited patiently for the rare moment when EVERYONE in the house was out, and went straight for the plastic bag the second she realized she **was** free

(boldface text to indicate which words would need to be changed)

It is difficult to recommend which tense is correct without seeing more of the surrounding text.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense.